# AWS + Celery + ElastiCache (Redis Cluster) Error: CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, celery, amazon-elasticache

I have a Dockerized Celery working on AWS, and it's using an ElastiCache (Redis Cluster with multi-nodes) from AWS as the message broker, but I'm getting the following error.

When I test my Celery workers on my local machine, it talked to a single node Redis totally fine. How should I fix this problem?

```
[I 180518 18:54:20 mixins:224] Connected to redis://....use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379//

[E 180518 18:54:20 events:123] Failed to capture events: 'CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot', trying again in 1 seconds.
```

...

```
[E 180518 18:54:23 events:123] Failed to capture events: 'Command # 1 (LLEN celeryev....2d788) of pipeline caused error: MOVED 11904 10.0.x.xxx:6379', trying again in 1 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because keys must be in the same hash slot and not just the same node. To implement multi-key operations in a sharded Redis (cluster mode enabled) ElastiCache cluster, the keys must be hashed to the same hash slot. You can force keys into the same hash slot by using hash tags.

I also recommend to check if your application support Redis using Cluster mode

More info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticache-crossslot-keys-error-redis/) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Clusters.Create.CON.RedisCluster.html)